# The button is not active in the form I prepared

Tags: javascript

I want to activate the button when the form is full. Where am I making mistakes?

button is not active.

Rules

- id="wbanka" - An option must be selected..
- id="saat" - It cannot be left blank.
- id="dakika" - It cannot be left blank.
- id="whavaletype" - An option must be selected..
- id="wcustomernote" - It cannot be left blank.
- id="xsayi" - A number between 250-1000 can be entered.And 10 and its multiples can be entered in numbers.

```js
$("#xsayi").on("keyup change", function () {
    var deger = $("#xsayi").val();
    if(deger.length) {
        if ($.isNumeric(deger)) {
            if (deger >= 250 && deger <= 1000) {
                if (deger % 10 == 0) {
                    check();
                    $("#xsayi").css("box-shadow","none");
                    $(".divide10, .range").hide();
                } else {
                    $(".range").hide();
                    $(".divide10").show();
                }
            } else {
                $(".fiyat > .number, .fiyat > .required, .divide10").hide();
                $(".range").show();
                $("#xsayi").css("box-shadow","0 0 7px red");
                $("#submit").prop("disabled", 1);
            }
        } else {
            $(".range, .fiyat > .required").hide();
            $(".fiyat > .number").show();
            $("#xsayi").css("box-shadow","0 0 7px red");
            $("#submit").prop("disabled", 1);
        }
    } else {
        $(".divide10, .range, .fiyat > .number").hide();
        $("#xsayi+.required").show();
    }
});

$("#wbanka").on("change",function () {
    var banka = $("#wbanka").val();
    if (banka==0) {
        $("#wbanka+span").show();
        $("#wbanka").css("box-shadow","0 0 7px red");
    } else {
        check();
        $("#wbanka").css("box-shadow","none");
        $("#wbanka+span").hide();
    }
});
$('#saat').on("keyup change", function () {
    var saat = $("#saat").val();
    if(!saat.length) {
        $("#saat+span").show();
        $("#saat").css("box-shadow","0 0 7px red");
        $("#saat+span").html("Zorunlu");
    } else if (saat>23) {
        $("#saat+span").show();
        $("#saat").css("box-shadow","0 0 7px red");
        $("#saat+span").html("Geçerli bir saat giriniz");
    } else  {
        check();
        $("#saat").css("box-shadow","none");
        $("#saat+span").hide();
    }
});
$('#dakika').on("keyup change", function () {
    var dakika = $("#dakika").val();
    if(!dakika.length) {
        $("#dakika+span").show();
        $("#dakika").css("box-shadow","0 0 7px red");
        $("#dakika+span").html("Zorunlu");
    } else if (dakika>60) {
        $("#dakika+span").show();
        $("#dakika").css("box-shadow","0 0 7px red");
        $("#dakika+span").html("Geçerli bir dakika giriniz");
    } else {
        check();
        $("#dakika").css("box-shadow","none");
        $("#dakika+span").hide();
    }
});
$("#whavaletype").on("change",function () {
    var whavaletype = $("#whavaletype").val();
    if (whavaletype==0) {
        $("#whavaletype+span").show();
        $("#whavaletype").css("box-shadow","0 0 7px red");
    } else {
        check();
        $("#whavaletype").css("box-shadow","none");
        $("#whavaletype+span").hide();
    }
});
$('#wcustomernote').on("keyup change", function () {
    var wcustomernote = $("#wcustomernote").val();
    if(!wcustomernote.length) {
        $("#wcustomernote+span").show();
        $("#wcustomernote").css("box-shadow","0 0 7px red");
    } else {
        check();
        $("#wcustomernote").css("box-shadow","none");
        $("#wcustomernote+span").hide();
    }
});

function check() {
    var banka = $("#wbanka").val();
    var miktar = $("#xsayi").val();
    var saat = $("#saat").val();
    var dakika = $("#dakika").val();
    var tip = $("#whavaletype").val();
    var odeme_yapan = $("#wcustomernote").val();

    if(banka!=0 && saat.length && saat<=23 && dakika.length && dakika<=60 && tip!=0 && odeme_yapan.length && miktar.length && $.isNumeric(miktar) && miktar>=250 && miktar <=1000 && miktar % 10 == 0) {
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", 0);
    } else {
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", 1);
    }
}
```

```html
<form class="pad0" id="FormHesabaHavale" name="FormHesabaHavale">
                                            <input  type="hidden" name="method" value="havale">
                                            <div class="register-wrap-finance">
                                            <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                                <label for="wbanka">Banka Adı</label>
                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-6 pad0">
                                                <select id="wbanka" required class="form-control input-sm width80" name="wbanka">
                                                    <option value="0">Banka Seçin</option>
                                                        <option value="İŞBANK">İŞBANK</option>
                                                        <option value="AKBANK">AKBANK</option>
                                                </select>
                                                    <span class="required" style="display:none;">Zorunlu</span>
                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-1 pad0"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="register-wrap-finance">
                                            <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                                <label for="wname1">İsim Soyisim</label>
                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-6 pad0">
                                                <input id="textarea" type="text" class="form-control input-sm width80"  value="Ad Soyad" readonly name="wname1">
                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-1 pad0"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="register-wrap-finance"  style="width:100%">
                                            <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                                <label for="wamount">Miktar</label>

                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-6 pad0 fiyat">
                                          <input id="xsayi" type="number" class="form-control input-sm width80" name="wamount" placeholder="Tutar Giriniz">
                                                <div class="required" style="display:none;">Bu alanı boş bırakamazsınız.</div>
                                                <div class="number" style="display:none;">Dogru miktar giriniz.</div>
                                                <div class="range" style="display:none;">Min (250 TRY), Max (20000 TRY)</div>
                                                <div class="divide10" style="display:none;">Miktar 10 ve katları şeklinde olmalıdır!</div>
                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-1 pad0"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="register-wrap-finance">
                                            <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                                <label for="whavaledatetime">Havale Saat/Dakika</label>
                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-2 pad0">
                                                <input id="saat" type="text" class="form-control input-sm width80" placeholder="Saat" name="whavalehour" maxlength="2" >
                                                <span class="required" style="display:none;">Zorunlu</span>
                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-2 pad0">
                                                <input id="dakika" type="text" class="form-control input-sm width80" placeholder="Dakika" name="whavaleminute" maxlength="2">
                                                <span class="required" style="display:none;">Zorunlu</span>
                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-3 pad0"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="register-wrap-finance">
                                            <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                                <label for="whavaletype">Nereden Yapıldı</label>
                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-6 pad0">
                                                <select id="whavaletype" class="form-control input-sm width80" name="whavaletype" >
                                                    <option value="0">Nereden Yapıldı</option>
                                                    <option value="ATM">ATM</option>
                                                    <option value="Banka (Online-Bankacılık)">Banka (Online-Bankacılık)</option>
                                                    <option value="EFT">EFT</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <span class="required" style="display:none;">Zorunlu</span>
                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-1 pad0"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="register-wrap-finance">
                                            <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                                <label for="wcustomernote">Ödemeyi yapan kişi adı</label>
                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-6 pad0">
                                                <input id="wcustomernote" type="text" class="form-control input-sm width80" placeholder="Ödemeyi yapan kişi adı" name="wcustomernote" maxlength="50">
                                                    <span class="required" style="display:none;">Zorunlu</span>
                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-1 pad0"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="register-wrap-finance deposit-bonus deposit-trader-bonus">
                                            <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                                <label for="wbonusid">Bonus Seçimi</label>
                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-6 pad0">
                                                <select id="wbonusid" class="form-control input-sm width80" name="wbonusid">
                                                    <option value="0">Bonus İstemiyorum</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-1 pad0"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="register-wrap-finance" style="width:100%;">
                                            <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                            </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-6 pad0">
                                                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="doDeposit('#FormHesabaHavale')" value="Ödemeyi Gerçekleştir" class="btn btn-success width80" disabled>
                                                </span>
                                                <span class="col-xs-1 pad0"></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the condition used in If statement are non relevent such as **.length**. below is rectified condition please check:

```
if(banka != '' && saat <= 23 && dakika <= 60 && tip != '' && $.isNumeric(miktar) && miktar >= 250 && miktar <= 1000 && miktar % 10 == 0){}
```

```js
$("#xsayi").on("keyup change", function() {
  var deger = $("#xsayi").val();
  if (deger.length) {
    if ($.isNumeric(deger)) {
      if (deger >= 250 && deger <= 1000) {
        if (deger % 10 == 0) {
          check();
          $("#xsayi").css("box-shadow", "none");
          $(".divide10, .range").hide();
        } else {
          $(".range").hide();
          $(".divide10").show();
        }
      } else {
        $(".fiyat > .number, .fiyat > .required, .divide10").hide();
        $(".range").show();
        $("#xsayi").css("box-shadow", "0 0 7px red");
        $("#submit").prop("disabled", 1);
      }
    } else {
      $(".range, .fiyat > .required").hide();
      $(".fiyat > .number").show();
      $("#xsayi").css("box-shadow", "0 0 7px red");
      $("#submit").prop("disabled", 1);
    }
  } else {
    $(".divide10, .range, .fiyat > .number").hide();
    $("#xsayi+.required").show();
  }
});

$("#wbanka").on("change", function() {
  var banka = $("#wbanka").val();
  if (banka == 0) {
    $("#wbanka+span").show();
    $("#wbanka").css("box-shadow", "0 0 7px red");
  } else {
    check();
    $("#wbanka").css("box-shadow", "none");
    $("#wbanka+span").hide();
  }
});
$('#saat').on("keyup change", function() {
  var saat = $("#saat").val();
  if (!saat.length) {
    $("#saat+span").show();
    $("#saat").css("box-shadow", "0 0 7px red");
    $("#saat+span").html("Zorunlu");
  } else if (saat > 23) {
    $("#saat+span").show();
    $("#saat").css("box-shadow", "0 0 7px red");
    $("#saat+span").html("Geçerli bir saat giriniz");
  } else {
    check();
    $("#saat").css("box-shadow", "none");
    $("#saat+span").hide();
  }
});
$('#dakika').on("keyup change", function() {
  var dakika = $("#dakika").val();
  if (!dakika.length) {
    $("#dakika+span").show();
    $("#dakika").css("box-shadow", "0 0 7px red");
    $("#dakika+span").html("Zorunlu");
  } else if (dakika > 60) {
    $("#dakika+span").show();
    $("#dakika").css("box-shadow", "0 0 7px red");
    $("#dakika+span").html("Geçerli bir dakika giriniz");
  } else {
    check();
    $("#dakika").css("box-shadow", "none");
    $("#dakika+span").hide();
  }
});
$("#whavaletype").on("change", function() {
  var whavaletype = $("#whavaletype").val();
  if (whavaletype == 0) {
    $("#whavaletype+span").show();
    $("#whavaletype").css("box-shadow", "0 0 7px red");
  } else {
    check();
    $("#whavaletype").css("box-shadow", "none");
    $("#whavaletype+span").hide();
  }
});
$('#wcustomernote').on("keyup change", function() {
  var wcustomernote = $("#wcustomernote").val();
  if (!wcustomernote.length) {
    $("#wcustomernote+span").show();
    $("#wcustomernote").css("box-shadow", "0 0 7px red");
  } else {
    check();
    $("#wcustomernote").css("box-shadow", "none");
    $("#wcustomernote+span").hide();
  }
});

function check() {
  var banka = $("#wbanka").val();
  var miktar = $("#xsayi").val();
  var saat = $("#saat").val();
  var dakika = $("#dakika").val();
  var tip = $("#whavaletype").val();
  var odeme_yapan = $("#wcustomernote").val();
  if (banka != '' && saat <= 23 && dakika <= 60 && tip != '' && $.isNumeric(miktar) && miktar >= 250 && miktar <= 1000 && miktar % 10 == 0) {
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", 0);
  } else {
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="pad0" id="FormHesabaHavale" name="FormHesabaHavale">
  <input type="hidden" name="method" value="havale">
  <div class="register-wrap-finance">
    <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                                <label for="wbanka">Banka Adı</label>
                                            </span>
    <span class="col-xs-6 pad0">
                                                <select id="wbanka" required class="form-control input-sm width80" name="wbanka">
                                                    <option value="0">Banka Seçin</option>
                                                        <option value="İŞBANK">İŞBANK</option>
                                                        <option value="AKBANK">AKBANK</option>
                                                </select>
                                                    <span class="required" style="display:none;">Zorunlu</span>
    </span>
    <span class="col-xs-1 pad0"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="register-wrap-finance">
    <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                                <label for="wname1">İsim Soyisim</label>
                                            </span>
    <span class="col-xs-6 pad0">
                                                <input id="textarea" type="text" class="form-control input-sm width80"  value="Ad Soyad" readonly name="wname1">
                                            </span>
    <span class="col-xs-1 pad0"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="register-wrap-finance" style="width:100%">
    <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                                <label for="wamount">Miktar</label>

                                            </span>
    <span class="col-xs-6 pad0 fiyat">
                                          <input id="xsayi" type="number" class="form-control input-sm width80" name="wamount" placeholder="Tutar Giriniz">
                                                <div class="required" style="display:none;">Bu alanı boş bırakamazsınız.</div>
                                                <div class="number" style="display:none;">Dogru miktar giriniz.</div>
                                                <div class="range" style="display:none;">Min (250 TRY), Max (20000 TRY)</div>
                                                <div class="divide10" style="display:none;">Miktar 10 ve katları şeklinde olmalıdır!</div>
                                            </span>
    <span class="col-xs-1 pad0"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="register-wrap-finance">
    <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                                <label for="whavaledatetime">Havale Saat/Dakika</label>
                                            </span>
    <span class="col-xs-2 pad0">
                                                <input id="saat" type="text" class="form-control input-sm width80" placeholder="Saat" name="whavalehour" maxlength="2" >
                                                <span class="required" style="display:none;">Zorunlu</span>
    </span>
    <span class="col-xs-2 pad0">
                                                <input id="dakika" type="text" class="form-control input-sm width80" placeholder="Dakika" name="whavaleminute" maxlength="2">
                                                <span class="required" style="display:none;">Zorunlu</span>
    </span>
    <span class="col-xs-3 pad0"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="register-wrap-finance">
    <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                                <label for="whavaletype">Nereden Yapıldı</label>
                                            </span>
    <span class="col-xs-6 pad0">
                                                <select id="whavaletype" class="form-control input-sm width80" name="whavaletype" >
                                                    <option value="0">Nereden Yapıldı</option>
                                                    <option value="ATM">ATM</option>
                                                    <option value="Banka (Online-Bankacılık)">Banka (Online-Bankacılık)</option>
                                                    <option value="EFT">EFT</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <span class="required" style="display:none;">Zorunlu</span>
    </span>
    <span class="col-xs-1 pad0"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="register-wrap-finance">
    <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                                <label for="wcustomernote">Ödemeyi yapan kişi adı</label>
                                            </span>
    <span class="col-xs-6 pad0">
                                                <input id="wcustomernote" type="text" class="form-control input-sm width80" placeholder="Ödemeyi yapan kişi adı" name="wcustomernote" maxlength="50">
                                                    <span class="required" style="display:none;">Zorunlu</span>
    </span>
    <span class="col-xs-1 pad0"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="register-wrap-finance deposit-bonus deposit-trader-bonus">
    <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                                <label for="wbonusid">Bonus Seçimi</label>
                                            </span>
    <span class="col-xs-6 pad0">
                                                <select id="wbonusid" class="form-control input-sm width80" name="wbonusid">
                                                    <option value="0">Bonus İstemiyorum</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </span>
    <span class="col-xs-1 pad0"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="register-wrap-finance" style="width:100%;">
    <span class="col-xs-5 pad0">
                                            </span>
    <span class="col-xs-6 pad0">
                                                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="doDeposit('#FormHesabaHavale')" value="Ödemeyi Gerçekleştir" class="btn btn-success width80" disabled>
                                                </span>
    <span class="col-xs-1 pad0"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```